# Regex matching for emotes

Tags: javascript, regex

I am implementing [Twitch.tv](http://twitch.tv) emotes on my site, but I'm having trouble with this regex. I'm 90% there, but there's one case that I don't know how to fix.

Here's the regex I have: (options are `gm`)

```
(^|\s+|&nbsp;)Kappa($|\s+)
```

The `Kappa` is replaced in a loop to check for different emotes. Here are my test cases. The second and third are not being detected. The second Kappa in each line is not being captured.

```
Kappa
Kappa Kappa
Kappa Kappa Kappa
KappaHD Kappa FrankerZ Kappa
Someone Said: Kappa
:&nbsp;&nbsp;Kappa
Kappa KappaHD Kappa
KappaKappa
```

If you're unfamiliar, these are the rules I want it to follow:

1. Find all instances of `Kappa` (`g` setting)
2. Can be at the beginning or end of the string / line of string (`m` setting)
3. Must be on its own, not in the middle of a word

The problem seems to be that the first `Kappa` is matching through the space after it, so the doesn't find the second one.

Here's a Regex101 with the sample code: https://regex101.com/r/fY0fN4/3

How can I get it to detect both instances of `Kappa` in `Kappa Kappa` properly?

I considered running a second find on `\sKappa\s` but that doesn't seem like the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler solution:

```
\bKappa\b
```

https://regex101.com/r/jG2wO4/1

The word boundaries "\b" will match, without consuming, everything that is not a word character.

Comment: @DLeh it will match `!@!@;Kappa;!@#` is it acceptable?

Comment: there may be some other edge cases that this might not help, but I was mostly going for a "whole word" kind of approach, and this seems to work fine. The biggest issue I was trying to solve with the original regex was that `Kappa` and `KappaHD` should have different resulting replacements. This also makes my replace easier as I just have to replace with the text I want and don't need a `$1`

Comment: @DLeh if you are sure that ur input will not have something like `Kappa!HD` then its fine :)

Answer (score 2):

```
(?:^|\s+|&nbsp;)Kappa(?=$|\s+)
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/zB3hI5/14

What you need is `lookahead` or else as you consume the `space` after first `Kappa` the second `Kappa` fails to match as `theres no space behind it`.SO use a `0 width assertion`.

Comment: looks like that will work great! thanks, I'm not familar with lookaheads

Comment: @DLeh `lookahead` is a `0 width assertion`.So it does not consume anything and just checks which is what we need here.Do accept if it worked for you.

Comment: This seems to have effected my replace functionality though, I will update my question to provide details on that.

Comment: I figured it out. My replace string was `$1replacement$2`, which was returning that exact string. i changed it to remove the `?:` in the first group, which allowed me to capture `$1` properly, then i just removed the `$2` from my replace.